# Fastest algorithm for evaluating large polynomials

Tags: multiplication, polynomial-math

A rather general question, what is the fastest (in terms of time complexity) algorithm for evaluating polynomials of Degree 400 to 500.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is one heck of a polynomial.

Comment: You may need to expand upon the question. What kind of input are you expecting? What language? Etc...

Comment: I'd ask on mathoverflow.com too.

Comment: What datatype? If you are dealing with floating point values, you need to consider numerical stability as well.

Comment: Your question's title suggests multiplication of more than one polynomial, not evaluating one. The multiplication problem is efficiently solved by Fourier transforms and convolutions.

Answer (score 10):

If you are talking about evaluation of polynomials, you probably can't be faster than the linear time [Horner scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme) - except if you have some special circumstances.

If you are talking about the multiplication of polynomials, the [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) is rather easy to implement and quite fast for that size. I believe fast Fourier transform based algorithms are only worth using if you have larger polynomials.

Comment: +1 for Horner...much better than my first glance (as always).

Comment: Horner is not only fast, but resistant to some instances of loss of precision erros that can plague really naive approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Modified versions of fast Fourier transforms (FFTs) generally provide very good results for this sort of problem. Take a look at **[this paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=806332)**, which suggests taking a hybrid FFT approach. I would start your research by looking for terms along the lines of "fast univariate FFT". It may also help you to note that multiplying two polynomials is essentially the same operation as multiplying two integers.